# deliver it "to safety" meaning?

Tags: expressions

> Steal the enemy’s warhead from their base and deliver it **to safety**

Does it mean "deliver safely" or "deliver it to a safe place"?

Answer (score 3):

The latter, I would say. Refers to location rather than mode of delivery.

Comment: I agree....  Can you document that?  I don't actually know if you can -- I haven't looked around -- but documentation is a nice way to strengthen an answer.